# Installing Qt3 on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: apt, 15.10, qt3

I wanted to try installing THELI (https://www.astro.uni-bonn.de/theli/) on my Ubuntu machine. In the installation notes it says that it needs qt3, and not qt4 or 5, for the GUI to work properly. I followed the instructions on the installations page and added:

```
  deb http://debian.tryphon.eu jessie main contrib
  deb-src http://debian.tryphon.eu jessie main contrib
```

to my */etc/apt/sources.list*, which works as it should. But now when I use:

```
sudo apt-get install qt3-dev-tools
```

I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qt3-dev-tools : Depends: libjpeg62-turbo (>= 1.3.1) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libqt3-mt (>= 3:3.3.8b) but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: libqt3-mt-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So what I took from that is, that *libjpeg62-turbo* was the problem here. After a little fiddling around I got apt to also install the *libtools62-turbo* which is an i386-Package (I think I got it working at least). After a new try of installing the *qt3-dev-tools* I still get the same error message, even though apt told me before that *libjpeg62-tools* was successfully installed.

I also tried to build qt3 from source, but that didn't work as well because I got some kind of error during the *make*-phase.

I would very much appreciate it if someone could help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: did you check your **software and updates**? Did you run `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: did you try this `sudo apt-get install qt3-dev-tools qt3-mt-dev` and did you install all the necessary packages?

Comment: yes I tried that already,  but for the *qt3-mt-dev* I got the error that apt was unable to locate the package, so I tried just installing *qt3-dev-tools*, which then ended up in the error explained above.
Also for the *libjpeg62-turbo* to be found by apt, I had to add another repository (https://packages.debian.org/jessie/i386/libjpeg62-turbo/download), if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Go to `synaptic package manager -> settings->repositories` and then from `update software` check all of them also check `other software`

Comment: @bhordupur when I do that I get the following errors:  
`W: GPG error: http://debian.tryphon.eu jessie Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:   
   NO_PUBKEY D080CEF3C6ADBBD5` for alle 3 links I added to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Run this command and will fix it `gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key D080CEF3C6ADBBD5 && gpg --export --armor D080CEF3C6ADBBD5 | sudo apt-key add -`

Comment: @bhordupur Thank you very much. That worked very well, and the installation went without any further problems

Comment: shall I put it as an answer so that others can get help from it.

Comment: yes, so I can mark it as the working answer, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal and run this :
`gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key YOURKEY && gpg --export --armor YOURKEY | sudo apt-key add -`

In your case:
`gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key D080CEF3C6ADBBD5 && gpg --export --armor D080CEF3C6ADBBD5 | sudo apt-key add -`

would fix this problem.